# My Ext.js function returning code not value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have some Ext.js code and I want to create a function that gets a date and returns it.
When I implament this code below, the dropdown list box where the dates are supposed to go shows the actual function code itself. Can anyone help?

```
                        fields: ['yearData', 'yearDisplay'],
                        //data: [['2012', '2012'], ['2013', '2013'], ['2014', '2014']]
                        data: [['2012', '2012'], ['2013', '2013'], [function () {
                            var d = new Date();
                            var n = d.getFullYear();
                            return n + 1;
                        }, function () {
                            var d = new Date();
                            var n = d.getFullYear();
                            return n + 1;
                        }]]
                    }),
                    displayField: 'yearDisplay',
```

In the dropdown list on the screen it shows (below) and not '2014'

```
                            function () {
                            var d = new Date();
                            var n = d.getFullYear();
                            return n + 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but you might try replacing the function

```
function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    return n + 1;
}
```

with the result of calling it:

```
(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    return n + 1;
})()
```

In this particular case, it may be clearer and more succinct to simply do

```
new Date().getFullYear()+1
```